# systemd - how to get it to show network config immediately following network startup?

Tags: networking, systemd

systemd *appears* to be starting the network OK but I want to see what it did.

I cannot ping the machine and I do not have command line access to it.

So is there a way to get systemd to not just say "Started network service", but also tell me the network configuration - i.e. I want to see the ifconfig output at that point.

How can I do this?

```
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target System Initialization.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Basic System.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Timers.
         Starting Network Service...
         Starting Permit User Sessions...
         Starting getty on tty2-tty6 if dbus and logind are not available...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Network Service.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Permit User Sessions.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started getty on tty2-tty6 if dbus and logind are not available.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Created slice system-getty.slice.
```

Answer (score 1):

`systemd` has a method for extending config files called "drop-in units". Try creating this file:

`/etc/systemd/system/networking.service.d`

In that file add:

```
[Service]
ExecStartPost=/sbin/ifconfig -a
```

The effect should be to extend the system networking service with an extra directive that runs after the service has started.

You can read more about drop-in units in `man systemd.unit`. You can find the docs for `ExecStartPost` and all other systemd directives by checking out `man systemd.directives`.